# Sorting pageBlockTable

Tags: sort

I'm verry sorry, but got some really terrible spaghetti code here.

Ids are passed to VF page with an extension which apparently has no function?

Anyhow, I've implemented sort which does work if I output results to console, but it does not actually work in VF. The meter_details__c still come out random (or sorted by record name). Is there a way to sort without using JavaScript?

Copy pasta below:

```
public class inputnulls { 
    ApexPages.StandardSetController mycon; 
    public List<Electricity_Meter__c> Selectedmeters {get; set;} 
    ID accId{get;set;} 
    public List<Electricity_Meter__c> Selectedmeters2 = new List<Electricity_Meter__c> ();    
    public class OpportunityWrapper implements Comparable {        
        public Electricity_Meter__c oppy;        
        public OpportunityWrapper(Electricity_Meter__c op) {
            oppy = op;
        }        
        public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
            OpportunityWrapper compareToOppy = (OpportunityWrapper)compareTo;            
            Integer returnValue = 0;
            if (oppy.Meter_Details__c  > compareToOppy.oppy.Meter_Details__c ) {
                returnValue = 1;
            } else if (oppy.Meter_Details__c  < compareToOppy.oppy.Meter_Details__c ) {
                returnValue = -1;
            }            
            return returnValue;       
        }
    }
    public inputnulls(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) { 
        accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        mycon = controller; 
        Selectedmeters = mycon.getSelected(); 
        OpportunityWrapper[] oppyList = new List<OpportunityWrapper>();
        for (Electricity_Meter__c met: selectedmeters ){
            oppyList.add( new OpportunityWrapper(met ));            
        }
        oppyList.sort();        
        for (OpportunityWrapper met: oppyList){
            selectedmeters2.add(met.oppy) ;
        }        
        selectedmeters = selectedmeters2;
        system.debug('Selected meters: '+selectedmeters);
        }

    public PageReference mySave() { 
        mycon.save(); 
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference( '/' + accId); //redirects back to id
        return pageRef ; 
    }     
}
```

**VF page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Electricity_Meter__c" recordSetVar="ElecMeters" extensions="inputnulls" tabStyle="Electricity_Meter__c" sidebar="false"> 
    <apex:form >    
            <apex:pageBlock title="Populate all fields with the same value" mode="edit" id="masspgblck">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Electricity_Meter__c}" var="mult" >
              <apex:column headerValue="Unique Identifier" footerValue="Unique Identifier">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!mult.Meter_Details__c}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="muselected"/>
                    </apex:inputField>
                    </apex:column>        
              </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>                  
        <apex:pageblock title="Selected Meters" id="muselected">
        <apex:pageMessages />                 
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >        
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>            
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>        
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="elecM">
                  <apex:column headerValue="Meter Details" footerValue="Meter Details">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!elecM.Meter_Details__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>
```

Comment: have you tried to use Selectedmeters in your pageblock table value attribute instead of Electricty_Meter__c?

Comment: Richard, first table is used to mass update the records in the second table. I am not exactly sure how this mechanism works, but it does. Now if I use selectedmeters inside second table I get error on runtime: `SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Electricity_Meter__c.Meter_Details__c`

Comment: Where you have {!selected} in the 2nd PBTable this is really looking at controller.getSelected(); which will return the values in a non-sorted way. You'll need to use SelectedMeters somewhere as this is your sorted list.